# Nginx+RTMP setups with USB camera

Tags: linux, nginx, camera, stream, rtmp

Basically, I connected a USB camera with Video4Linux 2 installed in ubuntu box. The camera is working with VLC:

```
vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
```

also I can save the camera stream with ffmpeg by:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -an -f flv MY_FLV.flv
```

I added following lines in rtmp section of nginx.conf file:

```
application webcam {                                                                   
        live on;                                                  
        record off;                                                   
        exec_static ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -an -f flv rtmp://localhost/webcam/live;                                              
 }
```

when I run nginx with rtmp, there is no stream out, could you please give me some ideas on this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is nginx compiled with `nginx-rtmp-module`? What's in nginx logs?

Comment: Yes, it's compiled with rtmp

Answer (score 1):

My bad, just need to put absolute path for ffmpeg

```
exec_static /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i ...
```

it works like charm...